# UICollectionView crash when moving items on iOS 16 beta

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` in which user can long tap and then move the items. I have implemented `func invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems` and `func invalidationContextForEndingInteractiveMovementOfItems` methods to handle this.

While testing on iOS 16 beta, app crashes when move an item.
Root cause is `previousIndexPaths` and `targetIndexPaths` both are become nil in below code. Any idea why this happens? On < iOS16 working fine.

```
open override func invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems targetIndexPaths: [IndexPath], withTargetPosition targetPosition: CGPoint, previousIndexPaths: [IndexPath], previousPosition: CGPoint) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
    
    let context = super.invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems: targetIndexPaths, withTargetPosition: targetPosition, previousIndexPaths: previousIndexPaths, previousPosition: previousPosition)
    
    //Check that the movement has actually happeneds
    if previousIndexPaths.first!.item != targetIndexPaths.first!.item {
        collectionView?.dataSource?.collectionView?(collectionView!, moveItemAt: previousIndexPaths.first!, to: targetIndexPaths.last!)
    }
    
    return context
}

open override func invalidationContextForEndingInteractiveMovementOfItems(toFinalIndexPaths indexPaths: [IndexPath], previousIndexPaths: [IndexPath], movementCancelled: Bool) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
    return super.invalidationContextForEndingInteractiveMovementOfItems(toFinalIndexPaths: indexPaths, previousIndexPaths: previousIndexPaths, movementCancelled: movementCancelled)
}
```

`UICollectionView` delegate method for moving item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    if self.longPressGesture.state == .ended {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        return
    }

    let cell = self.availableItems[sourceIndexPath.item]
    self.availableItems.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    self.availableItems.insert(cell, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
}
```

On iOS 16 `previousIndexPaths` and `targetIndexPaths` are nil
[image]

On iOS 15 `previousIndexPaths` and `targetIndexPaths` are have values
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by adding a delay it works for me now on iOS 16.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach worked for me as well