# Swift - beginInteractiveMovementForItem on iOS 16

Tags: swift, collectionview

on iOS 16 beginInteractiveMovementForItem in collectionvView throws an error:

```
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my code:

```
collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
```

Is there any alternative on iOS 16 to use?
There is another question similar here: [UICollectionView crash when moving items on iOS 16 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246265/uicollectionview-crash-when-moving-items-on-ios-16-beta/73887591#73887591) but still no answer for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by adding a delay it works now on iOS 16 as well.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
      collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
}
```